# DataGridView with Checkboxcolumn in tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, sql-server-2012

I have 1 tabcontrol with 3 tap pages..Each page contain 3 differtent datagrids which is connected to sql server tables like DGV1,DGV2,DGV3.. i have a checkbox column in these datagrids... i want to uncheck and cheack all all the three datagrids at a time... now my code only check the current tabpage.. soo that i need to know there is any way to check and uncheck all at a time... please help me...

```
Private Sub checkdgv()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV1.Rows
        row.Cells("sel1").Value = True
         TabControl1.SelectedTab =[tabcontrol1 for DGV1]
    Next
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV2.Rows
        row.Cells("sel2").Value = True
         TabControl1.SelectedTab =[[&tabcontrol1&] for DGV2]
    Next
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV3.Rows
        row.Cells("sel3").Value = True
         TabControl1.SelectedTab =[[tabcontrol1] for DGV3]
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub uncheckdgv()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV1.Rows
        row.Cells("sel1").Value = False
    Next
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV2.Rows
        row.Cells("sel2").Value = False
    Next
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV3.Rows
        row.Cells("sel3").Value = False
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try setting the focus on each tab, ie:

```
FOR EACH row as DataGridViewRow In DGV1.Rows
    row.Cells("sel1").Value = False
TabControl1.SelectedTab = [tabcontrol for DGV2]
FOR EACH row as DataGridViewRow In DGV2.Rows
    row.Cells("sel2").Value = False
```

...and so on.

Comment: Thank u Sooo Much for ur reply..bt this one is nt working.. i m getting an error with tabcontrol1 near for dgv1 .. eror messaGE..it can't be converted to system form..

Comment: updated code means what.. sorry i cant get u.. thanks for ur reply... @alybaba726

Comment: i had updated my new code for checkdgv.. still its showing error

Comment: Maybe me.DGV1.Focus()....then your function, same for DGV2, 3, 4. Without seeing your new code for setting the focus, I can't determine why you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

use tabcontrol.SelectTab(1) function to shift the focus the tab you would like to work. This has helped me